# Want to create a user input that once selected initiates a pre defined list

Tags: python, input, yfinance

So I've been trying to combine python and financials to create my own graphs and whatsnot. I have a basis for the code but wanted to make it more modifiable. My goal was to have a userinput section so as to allow the user to select which stock they would like to look at. On top of this I was hoping to have a certain input generate a predefined list of stocks. My code looks something like this:

```
symbol_input = input('Which stock would you like to analyse? (select stock using its trading symbol)')
if symbol_input == ('Electric cars'):
    symbol = ['NIO', 'TSLA', 'NKLA', 'FSR', 'FUV', 'KNDI']

symbol = symbol_input

start = datetime.datetime(2020,10,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

Stockdata = yf.download(symbol,start,end)


Stockdata['Adj Close'].plot(grid=True)
```

At the moment it won't recognise Electric cars as needing to generate the list of companies defined. Apologies if this a basic question I'm still pretty new to coding.

Im using JupyterNotebook

Comment: You're overwriting symbol on line 5

Comment: Roight Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try moving line 5 to inbetween line 1 and 2

Comment: Just tried this seems to be working thanks a mil pal